# Rectangles not appearing at specified position in React-Konva

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs

I am trying to draw small Rectangles on the corner of a selected Rectangle. The problem is they are not appearing at the corners.

I am drawing the bigger Rectangles dynamically and when I double click on any Rectangle they get selected (currently selected rectangle is stored in global variable SelectedRectangle) and the smaller rectangles must appear at the corner of the selected rectangle.

Please help me. This is my code -

```
var selectedRectangle = someSelectedRectangle;
export default class MyRectangle extends React.Component {        
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.selectShape = this.selectShape.bind (this);
      this.showCorners = this.showCorners.bind (this);
      this.drawRect = this.drawRect.bind (this);
  }

  selectShape (e) {
     if(selectedRectangle)
         this.showCorners ();
  }

  showCorners () {
    this.drawRect (selectedRectangle.x, selectedRectangle.y);
    this.drawRect (selectedRectangle.x + selectedRectangle.width, selectedRectangle.y);
    this.drawRect (selectedRectangle.x + selectedRectangle.width, selectedRectangle.y + selectedRectangle.height);
    this.drawRect (selectedRectangle.x, selectedRectangle.y + selectedRectangle.height);
  }

  drawRect (x, y) {    
    var layer = this.refs.layer;
    var rect = new Konva.Rect({
      x : {x},
      y : {y},
      width : 10,
      height : 10,
      fill : "black",
      draggable : "true",
    });

    layer.add(rect);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <Stage 
          ref = 'stage'
          width = {window.innerWidth} 
          height = {window.innerHeight}
        >
          <Layer ref = 'layer'>

            {this.state.shapes.map((shape) => {
              return (
                <Group>
                  <Rect
                    name = 'rect'
                    x = {shape.x}
                    y = {shape.y}
                    width = {shape.width}
                    height = {shape.height}
                    isDrawingMode = {this.state.isDrawingMode}
                    strokeWidth = {2}
                    draggable = "true"
                    stroke = "yellow"
                    fill = "green"
                    opacity = {0.4}
                    onDblClick = {(e) => this.selectShape(e)}
                  />                                         
                </ Group >
              );
            })} 

          </ Layer>
        </ Stage>
      </ div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not create/add rectangles manually if you are using react-konva. Instead, define them in render function.

Please create an online demo for your issue.

Comment: Here is the link for whole code. Its throwing error in this editor while working fine in Visual Studio Code editor in my system. Sorry but I haven't understood what you want to say. https://codesandbox.io/s/7zyqxrjj46

Comment: Is it neccessary to add rectangles in render function only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While developing with `react-konva` it is better not to touch Konva nodes manually. It means you should not add new nodes manually into a layer and you should not edit them manually (only in very rare cases when you know what you are doing).

So it is better to define the WHOLE view of your canvas in the `render()` function. That will be a declarative "react way".

Something like this:

```
render() {
  const cornerProps = {
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
    fill: 'black',
    offsetX: 5,
    offsetY: 5
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Stage
        ref="stage"
        width={window.innerWidth}
        height={window.innerHeight}
        onContentClick={this.handleClick}
        onContentMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}
      >
        <Layer ref="layer">
          {this.state.shapes.map((shape, index) => {
            return (
              <Group x={shape.x} y={shape.y}>
                <Rect
                  name="rect"
                  width={shape.width}
                  height={shape.height}
                  isDrawingMode={this.state.isDrawingMode}
                  strokeWidth={2}
                  draggable="true"
                  stroke="yellow"
                  fill="green"
                  opacity={0.4}
                  index={index}
                  onDragStart={e => this.handleDragStart(e)}
                  onDragEnd={e => this.handleDragEnd(e)}
                  onDblClick={e => this.selectShape(e)}
                />
                {index === this.state.selectedRectangleIndex && (
                  <Group>
                    <Rect x={0} y={0} {...cornerProps} />
                    <Rect x={shape.width} y={0} {...cornerProps} />
                    <Rect x={0} y={shape.height} {...cornerProps} />
                    <Rect x={shape.width} y={shape.height} {...cornerProps} />
                  </Group>
                )}
              </Group>
            );
          })}
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/8zwnmn5rx2

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping me. My problem is now solved